# How to run multiple OSes on multicore processor?

Tags: operating-system, embedded, multicore

I have a ARM processor which have 4 cores.
I would like to run one OS on the first two core and a different OS on the two others.
Is it at least possible ?
If it is, at which level do I have to configure that (BSP, OS, bootloader ...) ?

I already looked for hypervisors but that is not what I looking for.

I can't find anything, but it is probably that I don't know exactly what to look for !

Comment: That did not take much Google Foo:  https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/system/b/embedded-blog/posts/is-there-going-to-be-more-than-one-os-running-in-your-next-design

Comment: It would be wiser to use separate MCUs. Then each of them have complete control over I/O without fighting with its siamese twin over it.

Comment: Thank you Clifford for your answer, it is really useful !
May I know what keywords did you search for ? I'm new to this field of computer science.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible. I do not have much experience in ARM, but you can have multi OS environment across cores. Your primary OS can boot up first in one core and then it can load the secondary OS in RAM. Then the secondary core's reset vector can be set pointing to that location in the RAM and then you can start executing the secondary core from there.

You have to configure your boot loader to load the secondary OS in RAM, after primary OS is up. Based on architecture limitations, the secondary OS may/may not have access to RAM/ROM locations.